# Figure out which group has the most training group

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a bunch of groups. Each group entry is owned by another group entry. For example, the `soccer club` group owns `soccer training`, `soccer cardio squad`, `pro training` and `beginner training`. I want to find out which group owns the most `training` **type** group. To determine which group belongs to each other, I have a function called `groupOwnedBy()` which returns the `id` the group which owns the group.

For example, if we want to check which group owns `soccer training`, we pass in `2`, as that is the id for `soccer training`

```
SELECT * FROM groupOwnedBy(2);
```

will return the id of group, `1`, which owns `soccer training` (meaning it is owned by `soccer club`)

```
groupOwnedBy
------------
1
```

---

```
SELECT * from groupOwnedBy(1); -- will return 1. soccer club is owned by soccer club
```

**I want to print the name of the group which owns the most training type groups.** In this case it should print `soccer club`.

---

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
  id integer primary key,
  type text NOT NULL,
  name text
);


INSERT INTO groups (id, type, name) VALUES
(1, 'owner', 'soccer club'),          -- owned by soccer club
(2, 'training', 'soccer training'),   -- owned by soccer club
(3, 'cardio', 'soccer cardio squad'), -- owned by soccer club
(4, 'training', 'pro training'),      -- owned by soccer club
(5, 'training', 'beginner training'), -- owned by soccer club
(6, 'cardio', 'Cricket cardio team'), -- owned by cricket club
(7, 'owner', 'Cricket club'),         -- owned by cricket club
(8, 'training', 'Cricket training'),  -- owned by cricket club
(9, 'owner', 'Hockey club'),          -- owned by Hockey club
(10, 'owner', 'Kids Hockey')          -- owned by Hockey club
(11, 'training', 'smart train'),      -- owned by Hockey club
(12, 'training', 'fit train');        -- owned by Hockey club
```

---

I'm tried

```
SELECT name
FROM group
WHERE type = 'training'
GROUP BY ownedByGroup(id)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
ERROR: column "name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would group by the ownedByGroup(id) expression and get the max count(*).

After that you would join with the group table, in order to look up the name corresponding to the id as follows

```
select y.name,y.id 
  from (
    SELECT ownedByGroup(id) as max_training_grp_id
          ,count(*)
      FROM group
     WHERE type = 'training'
    GROUP BY ownedByGroup(id)
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1
       )x
   join group y
     on x.max_training_grp_id=y.id
```